# Turn a array into a variable for send in PHPMailer

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

Im trying to turn a array that haves another array from a SQL select into a unique variable to send it for users by PHPMailer, I tried to place the array on variable of PHPMailer so didnt works, thats why Im trying this way that looks a little bit difficult

```
public static function getUsersByEmail($email) {
    $sql = DB::prepare(
        "SELECT username FROM users WHERE email=:email ORDER BY id LIMIT 10"
    );
    $sql->bindParam('email', $email);
    $sql->execute();
    $accounts = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $accounts; // its array
}

public function recoverUsername($email) {
    if (User::emailHasAccounts($email) == true) {    
        $accounts = [User::getUsersByEmail($email)];               
        $str = implode(",", $accounts); // imploding array   

        $mail = new Mail([
            'email' => $email,
            'subject' => SITENAME,
            'template' => 'accountslist',
            'variables' => json_encode([
                'email' => $email, 
                'accountList' => $str, 
                'date' => date('d/m/y h:i')
            ]),
            'time' => time(),
            'next_attemp' => time(),
            'attemps' => 0,
            'status' => 0
        ]);

        // $mail->dbInsert();
        return true;
    } else {
        echo "erro";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check `print_r($accounts)`  -- it will be a two dimensional array like `array(array('username' = "name1"), array('username' => "name2"))`. You need to extract only the `username` from subarrays, perhaps `array_column($accounts, 'username')` which can then be used with `implode()`.

Comment: the problem is that im using 5.4, array column only came in 5.5, right?

Comment: Okay, if you can't use array_column(), then you need a loop. `foreach ($accounts as $a) { $usernames[] = $a['username']; }` and you can safely pass `$username` to `implode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (for PHP 5.5 <)

```
$accounts = getAccounts();
$rr = array_column($accounts, 'username');
$array = implode(',', $accounts);

$getaccounts = array_map(function ($accounts) {
    return $accounts['username'];
}, $accounts);

$var = implode('<br>', $getaccounts);
```